# Arangodb: Traversal using only 1 type of edges

Tags: arangodb

I have a edges collections with a "type" property.

What is an example of an AQL that traverse using only, for example,edge with type="A"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As could be expected, you use filters, e.g.:

```
FOR v, e, p IN 1..5 OUTBOUND 'collection/root' GRAPH 'graph'
    FILTER p.edges[*].type == "A"
    RETURN p
```

This query filters on the path `p`, the `1..5` litmits the length of paths considered.

The documentation on traversals covers a lot of ground and gives examples to get you started: https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/aql/graphs/traversals/

Comment: I tried this one. But it always return nothing. Does this work in 3.0.12 version?

Comment: Hm, it should -- the documentation for 3.0 is not different in this regard.

Comment: This is true. And for my exact purpose, I need to use FILTER p.edges[*].type ALL == "A"